# Lua - как отличить строку на кириллице от латиницы

Tags: строки, lua

Есть небольшой скрипт на `lua`, в котором используется длина строки. Как "отличить" кириллическую строку от латинской, так как её длина в два раза больше, что нарушит вычисления?

Comment: Строка может запросто состоять из символов разного размера. Вопрос, хотите вы знать длину в байтах или в символах.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10097941/4827341

Comment: А почему вам нужен обязательно кривой хак, а не правильное решение? Почему бы не узнать длину строки в символах и применить ей как надо?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, вопрос решен

Comment: @Yalikesifulei, так напишите в ответе, как именно решили. вполне возможно, что это ещё кому-нибудь пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

Упомянутая особенность "её длина в два раза больше" подсказывает, что речь идёт о кириллице закодированной в UTF-8. Детектировать в этом случае стоит не только наличие русских букв, а любого UTF-8, чтобы проверка срабатывала на любых данных.

В UTF-8 до однобайтная часть находится до 127-ой кодовой позиции, а всё остальное - многобайтное. Соответственно если в строке есть любой символ от 128 до 255 - она многобайтная и её надо обрабатывать по-особенному. Это элементарно проверяется regexp'ом.

```
local str = "123"
print(str:find("[\128-\255]"))
-- nil

local str = "abc"
print(str:find("[\128-\255]"))
-- nil

local str = "абв"
print(str:find("[\128-\255]"))
-- 1    1
```

Задачу "посчитать длину" для юникодной строки лучше выполнять какой-нибудь готовой библиотекой.

Answer (score 0):

Существует универсальное выражение для вычисления длины `utf-8` строк:

```
local len = #(str:gsub('[\128-\191]',''))
```